# Spring Security Authentication - Question about the Documentation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm looking at this page in the Spring Security JavaDoc:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#attemptAuthentication(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

What does this line mean?

> Return null, indicating that the
>   authentication process is still in
>   progress. Before returning, the
>   implementation should perform any
>   additional work required to complete
>   the process.

I'm working on a form that allows a user to log in and collects other data. I don't want to use the default UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter because I will then lose all the other data filled out in the form.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to capture more data from the login form is to use a custom WebAuthenticationDetails.

See [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100064-custom-WebAuthenticationDetails-xml-syntax-for-it-to-be-used) for info on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this line mean?

It generally means that if you return null from your overriden `attemptAuthentication()` method, the filter chain will be broken and no further filters will be invoked after the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. After which you are responsible for completing the authentication process, rather than the other filters along the chain.

You can have a look at the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#doFilter()` method source code line: 201.

In other words, returning `null` will cost you additional work.

If you want to override only `attemptAuthentication()` you should throw an `AuthenticationException` on unsuccessful authentication.

If you want to return `null` from `attemptAuthentication()` you should also override `doFilter()` and handle the `null` result yourself.