# How to customize Spring security Authentication to use 3 parameters?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am a bit new to Spring Security. Normally, we authenticate users using 2 parameters username and password. I have to configure the authentication process to use 3 parameters, which are account id, username and password. How should I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply implement username as a combination of two parameters like account_id@login.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way would be to use a custom `WebAuthenticationDetails`.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243794/sprint-security-authentication-question-about-the-documentation/6244764#6244764) answer.